# Is there a better way than xsl:variable to refer to an attribute value inside an XPath expression?

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I am using XSLT 2.0 to transform some XML. The source XML looks similar to this:

```
<AnimalTest>
  <AnimalTypes>
    <AnimalType name="cat"/>
    <AnimalType name="dog"/>
  </AnimalTypes>
  <Animals>
    <Animal name="Sylvester" typeName="cat"/>
    <Animal name="Fido" typeName="dog"/>
    <Animal name="Tom" typeName="cat"/>
  </Animals>
</AnimalTest>
```

Inside the XSL template to handle `AnimalType` tags, I want to use the `name` attribute of the `AnimalType` inside an XPath expression. The only way I have been able to achieve this, is by introducing a variable that holds the attribute `@name` and is referred from inside the XPath expression, like this:

```
<xsl:template match="AnimalType">
  <xsl:variable name="typename" select="@name"/>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="/AnimalTest/Animals/Animal[@typeName=$typename]"/>
</xsl:template>
```

This works, but I wonder whether I really have to use this temporary variable. Is there any better way to refer to that `@name` attribute? It looks like a detour to me.

Comment: If you're using the Saxon engine, then you don't need to worry about the variable in terms of execution speed - it'll optimize it out if there's only one call to it.

I'm not certain on the answer to your question, not unless you've already tried ``@typeName=./@name``

Comment: IMHO these little variables usually introduced to hold search criteria make your source code much more readable. And I would second @Vadi's opinion that they are definitely no performance issue.

Comment: @Vadi OK, execution speed was not my first concern but indeed something to consider when asking for something vague as a "better way". I already tried the solution you suggest but it does not work.

Comment: @MarcusRickert I agree that the XPath expression itself is more readable when using the variable. But it is somewhat inconvenient to have to look higher up in the code to see what value is assigned to the variable to exactly understand the XPath expression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really disliked using the variable, you could use the **current()** function to refer to the current context node (**AnimalType** in your case)

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="/AnimalTest/Animals/Animal[@typeName=current()/@name]"/>
```

If you had a more complex expression, using a variable can improve readability though, and you could potentially re-use in other places.

One thing to note is that his declaration

```
<xsl:variable name="typename" select="@name"/>
```

Is not quite the same as this declaration

```
<xsl:variable name="typename">
   <xsl:value-of select="@name" />
</xsl:variable>
```

Although both variables will contain the same value. In the latter case (using xsl:value-of) you are creating a copy of the value of the **name** attribute. In the former case, you are referring to the attribute directly. Therefore using the latter format would be less efficient.

As a slight aside, you may consider using a key here to look up your **Animal** elements by their typeName

```
<xsl:key name="AnimalByType" match="Animal" use="@typeName" />
```

That way, your apply-templates expression can be simplified to just the following

```
<xsl:template match="AnimalType">
   <xsl:apply-templates select="key('AnimalByType', @name)"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: You might like to note that in Saxon, using current() in this way is translated internally into the code you originally wrote using a variable. On the whole, my aesthetic preference is to use the variable.

Comment: Thanks for educating me with your answer to my question and beyond. The `current()` approach works for me indeed. I will start using it and see how I like it.

Comment: @MichaelKay I am using Saxon indeed, thanks for the remark. I have not decided about my preference yet...